# Package listings and new language definition

Tags: listings

I tried to define a few PowerShell cmdlets for the `lstlisting` environment, but it seems that the `-` breaks the definition. So when I try:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{powershell}{
    keywords = {Get-AzureSubscription,Get-Host,anything}
}
```

only the keyword `anything` is detected. Do I have to escape the `-`, and how?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As per the manual on https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings?lang=en you should put `alsodigit = {-}` in your language definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Marijn said in his comment you should add `alsodigit = {-}` in your definition:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{powershell}{
    alsodigit = {-},
    keywords = {Get-AzureSubscription,Get-Host,anything}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=powershell]
text anything Get-AzureSubscription
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```